# In AngularJs which way is better while using ng-if, is to perform the condition in the template or call a function that return true or false

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<!-- template.html -->
<div ng-if="items.length > 0">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
```

vs

```
<!-- template.html -->
<div ng-if="$ctrt.hasItems()">
    <!-- content -->
</div>

<!-- controller.js -->
$ctrt.hasItems = (itmesList) => {
    return items.length > 0
};
```

which way is better, doing the evaluation in javascript or in the HTML template?

Comment: For writing testable code the second option is better

Comment: the second approach will run the function more than once; use the first example

Comment: which kind of testing you mean, you mean unit testing? @brk

Comment: @AlekseySolovey could you explain why the $ctrt.hasItems() will run more than once?

Answer (score 0):

The second example will run the function multiple times. I think it's because angular doesn't know if any `$scope` value has changed during each digest cycle. So the function will get executed for each digest cycles. In your case, it will get executed when the `ng-if` conditions become true.

Here is a demo that would replicate this behaviour:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [1, 2, 3];
  var x = 0;
  $scope.hasItems = function() {
    x++;
    console.log("execution", x);
    return $scope.items.length > 0;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  Test:
  <div ng-if="hasItems()">Has items</div>
</div>
```

It's always better to populate the variable in the controller, rather than check for that variable's value with any get method / function. So use your first case, where you check it directly.

Comment: but the problem here is what inside `ng-if` will get executed twice not about the `hasItems()`, so that means if I used `items.length > 0` that also will be executed more than one time? right? @Aleksey Solovey

Comment: @HameedGamal I'm not sure, digest cycles are complicated. But using functions usually triggers any dirty checking before it renders anything